# ¿Cómo comprimir carpetas de subdirectorio con tarfile desde python?

Tags: python, tar

Quiero comprimir unas subcarpetas con tarfile en python:

Tengo una carpeta "PRINCIPAL" y dentro de "PRINCIPAL" tengo "CARPETA1","CARPETA2","CARPETA3" las cuales quiero comprimir en .tar

Tengo un script que me comprime "PRINCIPAL" con todo su contenido, pero yo quiero que el resultado sea CARPETA1.tar, CARPETA2.tar, CARPETA2.tar. ¿Existe una forma de hacer eso?

```
ruta = /home/PRINCIPAL/
carpeta = []
carpeta = os.listdir(ruta)
for name in carpeta:
    tarfile = tarfile.open(name+".tar", "w:gz")
    tarfile.add(name)
    tarfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, no hagas ésto:

```
tarfile = tarfile.open(name+".tar", "w:gz")
^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^
```

en la siguiente iteración la variable `tarfile` ya no apunta al módulo `tarfile` importado, sino al  objeto `tarfile.TarFile` retornado por `tarfile.open` en la iteración anterior.

En mi opinión `os.scandir` es preferible a `os.lisdir`, no solo por eficiencia, sino porque retorna objetos `os.DirEntry` de los cuales es mucho más simple obtener la ruta, nombre base, etc.

Por otro lado, debes pasar a `tarfile.open` la ruta del archivo .tar de salida y al método `add` debes pasar primero la ruta de la subcarpeta de turno de `PRINCIPAL` y a su argumento `arcname` el nombre base de dicha carpeta, o te reproducirá todo el árbol de archivos.

Si como supongo quieres que las posibles subcarpetas también se agreguen, usa el argumento `recursive`.

```
import os
import tarfile


ruta = "/home/PRINCIPAL/"

for obj in os.scandir(ruta):
    if obj.is_dir():
        with tarfile.open(f"{obj.path}.tar", "w:gz") as file:
            file.add(obj.path, arcname=obj.name, recursive=True)
```

Los .tar se crean en `/home/PRINCIPAL`, si quieres que se creen en el directorio de trabajo del script, cambia `f"{obj.path}.tar"` por `f"{obj.name}.tar"`. Si los quieres en otra ruta, usa `os.path.join()` para componerla y pásala a `tarfile.open`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó. Gracias otra vez.